# How to connect to Quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

We are using `Quickbooks Enterprise 13.0` locally hosted on a windows.
I am working on a system, that needs to send invoices to quickbooks. 
I am developing in `Java`, `deploy on JBoss 7`, and it will be hosted in `Amazon Cloud` on 
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze)

How should I connect to our locally hosted Quickbooks ? With the Rest API or the `QuickBooks QBXML SDK`.

I have no experience with quickbooks. Do I need to setup quickbooks to allow incoming requests ?

Comment: Is this a SaaS app (e.g. you are allowing many people to connect their QuickBooks to your app, and charging them a recurring fee to do so)? (there are two ways to connect to QB, which one you can use depends on your answer to the above question)

Comment: My system, a java app, will be the only app ( for now ) connection to QB. Our QB is not accessible for any other companies, and no other QB will connect to my app.

Answer (score 2):

The REST APIs are only for SaaS applications (e.g. you have to be offering your integration with QuickBooks for sale to many other companies, allowing them to connect their QuickBooks to your app). If you're not SaaS, you can't use the REST APIs (Intuit Anywhere).

Instead, you can use the qbXML SDK.

If QuickBooks is on the *same computer* that your app is on, you can use the SDK's COM components (there are examples in the QuickBooks SDK if you download it) to connect to QuickBooks.

If it's a web app on a different machine, use the Web Connector. There's a big 100+ page PDF of the Web Connector in the QuickBooks SDK documentation. We also have an overview on our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector).

Comment: Ok, so I have to "install" the web connector on the windows that has QB. ? and then use the qbXML SDK to connect to the web connector ? or do I use QuickBooks SDK

Comment: The QuickBooks SDK is the QuickBooks SDK - there's only one, not multiple. The SDK speaks qbXML - either straight qbXML, or qbXML generated by the QBFC classes. The Web Connector is bundled with all newer versions of QuickBooks, you just need to feed it a .QWC file to configure it.

Comment: oh ok thanks, the web connector, as you say, was already there, and I created a qwc file that was loaded successfully. Next step is to implements the webservice part in my app.

Comment: Isn't there a SDK that I don't have to install. We are developers working on windows and linux. I thought there would be a java SDK, some jar files I could use. I do not want to install a SDK. ???
I see examples where com.intuit.developer.ArrayOfString is used.. where is that class coming from.. ?

Comment: You *don't* need to install the SDK. Installing it gives you access to some documentation, code samples, and troubleshooting tools, but that's it. Everything you actually need is included with QuickBooks out of the box. If you have questions about specific code, you should probably post the code so that people can see what you're talking about.